# Can't get PostgreSQL data to show on Heroku - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am making a Rails API using jbuilder to serve as my database for a React app I'm building. I am using PostgreSQL. I can get the index.json.jbuilder view to work on my local server:

```
{
 "owners": [
   {
    "first_name": "Alex",
    "last_name": "Hardy",
    "revenue": 100000,
    "audit_score": 89,
    "passing": true,
  },   ...........
{
```

But these instances are not going to Heroku's server. I have created the heroku app, pushed my app to heroku (git push heroku master) , and migrated the database with:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

It has stored the tables because when I run:

```
Heroku pg:info
```

I get:

```
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 2/20
PG Version:  9.6.2
Created:     2017-07-26 19:09 UTC
Data Size:   7.4 MB
Tables:      3
Rows:        2/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
Add-on:      postgresql-contoured-63642
```

If I

```
heroku console
```

and check for the table Owner (Owner.new) it shows up with the correct properties ("first_name", "last_name"....). BUT, when I go to the site: https://peaceful-basin-47322.herokuapp.com/owners it only shows the table, with none of the instances of that model:

```
{
    "owners": []
}
```

How to I migrate the instances of my model to Heroku?

Comment: the data from your localhost is difference, with the data in your heroku.

Answer (score 2):

the data from your localhost is Different, with the data in your heroku.
if you want it to be same you need dump your data from your localhost then import it to your heroku,

first dump your postgres localhost data

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

then upload it to internet where heroku can download it, like amazon s3

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump' DATABASE_URL
```

more you can read here
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

rake `db:migrate` only create the database tables, without the data, if you want to also create the data you can make it from `seeds.rb` and then do `rake db:seed`

Comment: Thanks @icemelt. I can't believe I forgot to seed my database. I am a little confused on your commands though. I am trying to do the first command to::: dump the postgres localhost data::::...but.... where do I run that command? In the heroku console? because if I just do that in my directory nothing is going to happen. I have had success in the past seeding my local db and then running::::: heroku run rake db:migrate, but for some reason that isn't working now. Any thoughts?

Comment: To dumb the postgres data, just put the command in your own computer terminal. To import it run the command from heroku console/ heroku run command

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way if you just want to populate the DB in heroku with your local DB contents is to do, on your terminal, from your app folder:

```
heroku pg:info
# this will show you something like:
# === HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED
# Plan         Standard 0
# ...

# then with this you have the DB name HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED, do

heroku pg:push your_local_db_name_here HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED --app change_to_your_app_name
```

If your database is not empty it will ask you to do `pg:reset` first. Remember you need a clean database to do this, if you want to mix your records from local into an existing DB then you need to do it in other ways.

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull

Comment: Thanks @micael nussbaumer! You are the MAN! That is the first thing that worked for me. It's true, I did have to reset my db, but at least it's up there and that is a start. I really appreciate it :)!